# Desplazarse por los Inputs con las flechas del teclado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quisiera saber cómo puedo cambiar el *focus* entre dos inputs que están en diferentes `<div>` con las flechas derecha e izquierda usando javascript/jquery, aquí el código:

```html
<div class="table-section" id="IpatCOp1-2">     
  <div class="md-form">
    <label class="label-input" for="IpatCOp1-org">No.</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" size="10" maxlength="8" id="IpatCOp1-org" tabindex="10"/>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form w-50">
    <label class="label-input" for="nomorganismo">NOMBRE</label>
    <input type="text" id="nomorganismo" class="w-100 input" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Gracias.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que con esto estarás perjudicando gravemente la accesibilidad de tu aplicación, haciendo así que cuando estas en un input y escribes algo no te puedas mover por la cadena con las flechas.

Comment: Hola @x3k_js  tienes razón, sin embargo es requerimiento del usuario, gracias por tu comentario.

Answer (score 2):

Para moverte por los inputs a través de las teclas direccionales (`right` y `left`, también puede funcionar con `up` y `down`) puedes emplear jquery a través del evento `keyup` y una función que encuentre el siguiente o anterior elemento del input actual.

En este ejemplo en caso de llegar al limite se regresa al primero o al ultimo según el caso:

```js
$(function() 
{
  $('.input').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==37)//38 para arriba
      mover(e,-1);
    if(e.keyCode==39)//40 para abajo
      mover(e,1);
  });
});


function mover(event, to) {
   let list = $('input');
   let index = list.index($(event.target));
   index = (index + to) % list.length;
   list.eq(index).focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-section" id="IpatCOp1-2">     
  <div class="md-form">
    <label class="label-input" for="IpatCOp1-org">No.</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" size="10" maxlength="8" id="IpatCOp1-org" tabindex="10"/>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form w-50">
    <label class="label-input" for="nomorganismo">NOMBRE</label>
    <input type="text" id="nomorganismo" class="w-100 input" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form w-50">
    <label class="label-input" for="nomorganismo">input3</label>
    <input type="text" id="input3" class="input" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form w-50">
    <label class="label-input" for="nomorganismo">input4</label>
    <input type="text" id="input4" class="w-100 input" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo solo se puede navegar hasta los limites hacia arriba y abajo:

```js
$(function() 
{
  $('.input').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==37)//38 para arriba
      mover(e,-1);
    if(e.keyCode==39)//40 para abajo
      mover(e,1);
  });
});


function mover(event, to) {
   let list = $('input');
   let index = list.index($(event.target));
   index = Math.max(0,index + to);
   list.eq(index).focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-section" id="IpatCOp1-2">     
  <div class="md-form">
    <label class="label-input" for="IpatCOp1-org">No.</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" size="10" maxlength="8" id="IpatCOp1-org" tabindex="10"/>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form w-50">
    <label class="label-input" for="nomorganismo">NOMBRE</label>
    <input type="text" id="nomorganismo" class="w-100 input" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form w-50">
    <label class="label-input" for="nomorganismo">input3</label>
    <input type="text" id="input3" class="input" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form w-50">
    <label class="label-input" for="nomorganismo">input4</label>
    <input type="text" id="input4" class="w-100 input" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Construí la función `mover()` en base a este [código](https://jsfiddle.net/55pmmzd6), créditos a su autor.

Espero sea lo que estas buscando, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Estuve usando esta función:

```js
 $(".table-section").keydown(function (e) {
  var items = $(this).find('.input'),
  activo = document.activeElement;
  
  if (e.which == 39) {
    //ciclo for que valida si NO es el último 
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++) {
      if(activo === items[i]){
        items[i + 1].focus();
      }
    }
  }
  if (e.which == 37) {
    //ciclo for que valida si NO es el primero
    for (var i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (activo === items[i]) {
        items[i - 1].focus();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-section">     
  <div class="md-form">
    <label class="label-input">No.</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" size="10" maxlength="8" tabindex="10"/>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form w-50">
    <label class="label-input">NOMBRE</label>
    <input type="text" class="w-100 input" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form w-50">
    <label class="label-input">input3</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="md-form w-50">
    <label class="label-input">input4</label>
    <input type="text" class="w-100 input" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Se ve interesante, aunque produce error al llegar a los limites, habría que corregir ese detalle.

Comment: Ya está corregido para que no no valide el anterior si es el primero o el siguiente si es el último. Saludos.